# How to temporary turn off seamless mode of VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

I use Deskpin to nailed the virtual machine to be on top by using hotkey `Ctrl-F12`. But in `seamless mode`, I cannot do that since every time I click the guest machine's window, the mouse go inside the OS immediately.

So, is there a way to disable it temporary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround for this is to use the other way to nail the window as below snapshot; i.e. using the mouse click instead of using hotkey.

@1 click the Deskpin icon

The cursor turns into @2 and then we click the guest machine, it will be nailed on top resulting as @3

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 14):

HOST KEY + L

OR

RIGHT CTRL + L

is the default key for turn on/off seamless mode for virtualbox

Comment: Far out, that's a trap! I can't find any other way to exit seamless mode... :/

Answer (score 2):

Here is how i did it:

The win7 start bar was barely visible at the bottom of the screen. All I had to do is click on the part that was visible and THEN press the Host key ( which is right CTRL) plus L.